# Gradient between two custom colours on canva?

Tags: gradient, canva

To create a gradient between two colours on canva

> Enter "Gradient" on the search bar, and click on any of the results. To edit the gradient colour, click the colour tile on the toolbar above the editor

After doing so, it seems to allow only *one* of the two gradient colours to be selected and changed (the other remains the colour of the original).

E.g. here the green is selected by me

[image]

but the pink colour stays no matter what is click on. Is it possible to select ***both*** the colours in a gradient background in canva? I.e. in the case above, change the pink colour to something else, or is it predetermined by the background selected and therefore not possible to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Elements, there's a gradient element that allows you to choose both color options.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

2 elements can be used here:

1. Under elements search "Gradient that fades to transparency". You'll be able to add 2 colors. If you don't want it to fade to transparency, just put an extra colored square behind.
2. Under elements search "Recolorable Two Color Gradient". At the moment this element is not working for me, but assuming it'll be back as it was made by Canva.

Note! On both these options, use the crop feature or a frame to help you resize as it'll stay square.